# OR clause in swift generics

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift5

So, I am trying to write a network library from scratch, and I am trying to utilise generics.

I'm using URLComponents to generate URL

my URLComponent extension looks like this

```
 extension URLComponents {
        /*mutating func setQueryItems(params : [Argument<Any>]){
            
            let q = params.map{ item in
               
                if let value = item.valueName.getValue {
                     URLQueryItem(name: item.keyName, value: value)
                }
            }
            
             self.populateQueryItems(queryItems: q)
        }*/
        
        
        mutating func setQueryItems(params : [Argument<Bool>]){
            let q = params.map{ item in
                URLQueryItem(name: item.keyName, value: item.getValue)
            }
            
             self.populateQueryItems(queryItems: q)
        }
        
        mutating func setQueryItems(params : [Argument<Double>]){
            let q = params.map{ item in
                URLQueryItem(name: item.keyName, value: item.getValue)
            }
            
             self.populateQueryItems(queryItems: q)
        }
        
        mutating func setQueryItems(params : [Argument<String>]){
            let q = params.map{ item in
                URLQueryItem(name: item.keyName, value: item.valueName)
            }
            
            self.populateQueryItems(queryItems: q)
        }
        
        mutating private func populateQueryItems(queryItems : [URLQueryItem]){
            if self.queryItems == nil {
                self.queryItems = queryItems
            }else {
                self.queryItems?.append(contentsOf: queryItems)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Argument struct

```
struct Argument<T> {
    var keyName : String
    var valueName : T
}

extension Argument where T == Int {
    var getValue : String{
        return valueName.description
    }
}

extension Argument where T == Double {
    var getValue : String{
        return valueName.description
    }
}

extension Argument where T == Bool {
    var getValue : String{
        return valueName.description
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the extension of URLComponent the function setQueryItems is overloaded multiple times having the same body, because the Argument's Type T is different. I need to work a way out of this mess.

I thought if there is a way to include OR logic in the where clause, but there's no such way.

How can I improve this logic and remove redundant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case generics is the wrong approach.

The common denominator of the generic type of `Argument` is the protocol `CustomStringConvertible` , all types which adopt the protocol have a `description` property.

Declare the struct non-generic

```
struct Argument {
    var keyName : String
    var valueName : CustomStringConvertible
    
    var value : String { return valueName.description }
}
```

and the `URLComponents` extension can be reduced to

```
extension URLComponents {
    mutating func setQueryItems(params : [Argument]){
        let q = params.map{ item in
            URLQueryItem(name: item.keyName, value: item.value)
        }
        self.populateQueryItems(queryItems: q)
    }
    
    mutating private func populateQueryItems(queryItems : [URLQueryItem]){
        if self.queryItems == nil {
            self.queryItems = queryItems
        }else {
            self.queryItems?.append(contentsOf: queryItems)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

If you want to consider also arrays you have to extend the `value` property for example

```
struct Argument {
    var keyName : String
    var valueName : CustomStringConvertible
    
    var value : String {
        if let valueArray = valueName as? [CustomStringConvertible] {
            return valueArray.map{$0.description}.joined(separator: "-")
        } else {
            return valueName.description
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that looks plausible but what if I need to pass an array to the queryItems of the URLComponents, in a particular manner, say [1,2,3] must be shown as 1-2-3?